# Normed Vector Spaces Query

Tags: functional-analysis

Theorem: Let $V$ be a normed vector space and let $S=\left\{x \in V : \|x\|\le1\right\}$. Then $S$ is closed.

I know that I am supposed to show that for any sequence $\{x_n\}$ there a point $x$ in $S$ such that $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=x$.

But for some reason I keep messing this up!!

If anyone could help then that would great!

Answer (score 1):

In order to show that $S$ is closed, you are rather supposed to show that any convergent sequence $(x_n)$ (with $x_n \in S$ for all $n$) converges in $S$.

Another possibility is to notice that $$f : \left\{ \begin{array}{ccc} V & \to & \mathbb{R} \\ x & \mapsto & \| x \| \end{array} \right.$$ is continuous and that $S= f^{-1}([0,1])$.

Comment: Am I still supposed to use some sort of epsilon-delta argument to show this?

Comment: To show that $f$ is continuous, it is sufficient to show that $f$ is Lipschitz. It is just the reversed triangle inequality: $\| x-y \| \geq | \|x\| - \|y\| |$.

Comment: I have never studied Lipschitz so I think I am to show this using the convergent sequences in S.

Comment: Otherwise, by definition, saying that $f$ is continuous is just: $\forall \epsilon>0, \forall x \in V, \exists \delta>0, \forall y \in V, \|x-y\| < \delta \Rightarrow | \|x\|-\|y\| | < \epsilon$. The statement is true for $\delta=\epsilon$ thanks to the reversed triangle inequality.

Comment: You can also say that for all sequence $x_n \to x$ in $V$ we have $\|x_n \| \to \|x\|$, again thanks to the reversed triangle inequality.

Comment: ... still can't get this thing to work.

Comment: Where is your problem?

Comment: I eventually got it using sequential characteristics of closed sets.